# How to find out who is hosting my Wordpress site?

Tags: html, wordpress, web, dns, hosting

I am taking over a wordpress site for a company. They don't know who is currently hosting their wordpress site, all they have is the domain name hoster and the wordpress site admin login info.

Comment: Have you tried `whois`?

Comment: you can try http://www.whoishostingthis.com/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to check the DNS the domain name is pointed to. You may check the nameservers (=DNS) in public Whois database: https://www.whois.net/

Also, this resourse should help: http://www.whoishostingthis.com/

Answer (score 3):

I have used quite a few, but depending on the database they work with, some deliver wrong info. The best one currently is [Hosting Checker](http://hostingchecker.com/) and [Who Is Hosting This](https://www.whoishostingthis.com/) comes second.

Answer (score 2):

see this website http://www.whoishostingthis.com/ It worked for me

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you already know who hosts the domain, you're just looking to find out where the actual files are being served from. If that's correct, you should try:

ping theirdomain.tld

When you ping the domain, it will give you the IP address where the files are hosted. You can plug that IP address back into whois, you'll find out who actually owns that IP address.

For example, if I want to find out where my company's website is located, I would do:

- ping 0708scompany.tld
- copy the ip address.
- whois ip.address.from.ping

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `whois yourdomain.com` and it should give you the relevant information. It will provide you with the DNS, who the domain name is registered with, and a whole lot more.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `whois`. Just google `whois` and you can figure out how. If you have it installed, type `whois domain.com` in a terminal. You could also use [whois.icann.org](http://whois.icann.org) or other `whois` sites.

`whois` tells name, address, and other things. You can use it on *any* site, so it is indeed very useful.