# How to find out where my website is hosted

Tags: hosting

I've looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40620653/how-to-find-out-who-is-hosting-my-wordpress-site) and it doesn't solve my problem.

---

I just switched to a new site builder.  Previously I was using Kajabi.  Now i'm using GroovePages (GP).  I switched DNS Settings in GoDaddy to GP's custom DNS servers, but now I am seeing 2 different websites when I go to the WWW version and the NON-WWW version of my website.  The NON-WWW is correctly showing the page i built on GP, whereas the NON-WWW is not.

To make a long story short, I've been through long email threads with each company and seems like neither one knows how/why the WWW is not properly routing to the new site.  GroovePages claims they have proper CNAME record set, as they are the ones managing the DNS records.  Kajabi claims to have reset any lingering records also.

Currently the WWW version is pointing to Heroku, but I don't even have a Heroku account and haven't used them to host my website.

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure when you setup Forwarding that you forward to [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) instead of mysite.com

Link to forward my domain: https://in.godaddy.com/help/forward-my-domain-12123

[image]

Comment: I am using Custom DNS in GoDaddy, pointing to Cloudflare (which is used by GroovePages) which means I don't have ability to forward DNS or manage my DNS records using GoDaddy.  GroovePages is doing that for me and they have setup the proper CNAME records.  The problem is somehow the Kajabi records are interfering (I think)...